# Installing Lubuntu on Old Computer

Tags: linux, windows, lubuntu, unetbootin

I am trying to revive an old computer of mine. It is a Dell Inspiron 9300 running Windows XP.

I am using unetbootin with Grub to install Lubuntu, however when I try to install after restarting the computer I receive an error message along the lines of this:

```
casper vmlinuz not found error 15
```

Is this install requiring an internet connection? I am not sure this laptop can connect to the internet in the bios, I also tried installing with an ethernet cable connected an was still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

look for a directory named /casper/ and change the file named "vmlinuz.efi" to "vmlinuz" *without* ".efi".
or, if the file is named vmlinuz add ".efi" in the end.
the answer is from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257078/casper-vmlinuz-not-found), next time google before you ask

Comment: I added the extension to the vmlinuz file now I get another error 15: find --set-root /unetbtin/ubnkern